# Give default value when viewing data on php

Tags: php, mysql

i have try to get data with following code

```
$result = $viral->getData("SELECT * FROM preview WHERE id=$id");

foreach ($result as $res) {
  $title = $res['title'];
  $promoted = $res['promoted'];
  $photo = $res['file'];
}
```

and i view query result with this code

```
<p><?php echo $title;?></p>
```

i want when value $title in database is blank it will automatically replace by my default value.

Can i give default value when variable $title is blank ?

Comment: Yes of course you can see my answer below

Comment: On Stack Overflow every question is asking something. There's no need to specify that in the title.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $title = $res['title'];
 echo "<p>" . (($title == "" || $title == NULL) ? "Default Value" : $title) . "</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this, please try

```
$result = $viral->getData("SELECT * FROM preview WHERE id=$id");

foreach ($result as $res) {
  $title = empty($res['title'])? "Your Default Valur or Variable":$res['title'];
  $promoted = $res['promoted'];
  $photo = $res['file'];
}
```

or if you only go with `$title` variable use this

```
empty($title)? "Your Default Valur or Variable":$title;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$title = $res['title'];
if (empty($title){
    $title = "assign default title";
}
```